# explore and represent a file/folder tree

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is not an implementation but a more theoric one, I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but I'll give it a shot.

The place i work at store all of the files on a server but some files tend to disappear. By the time we realize it a few days may have passed and coming back to the backup can be painful. Furthermore we may not notice it before a while...

Hence I would like to develop an application to screen the entire server content, at least once a day, to spot files or folder that were added, moved, or most importantly deleted.

So these are my interrogations:

1) Is this doable? I mean, of course I know it can be done but given the amount of file will it take hours to run, or can I expect it to run in a few minutes?

2) How would you choose to represent the final tree. Would you highlight only the paths that were broken, but assuming a folder disappears then all of sub folders and files will be missing too... Should I choose to graphically represent the entire tree? But if so how would you choose to implement such a representation? I would go with an HTML report but I used HTML reporting for basic tasks only so I am not sure how hard this could get?

Thanks for your help and thoughts.

PS: I do have an implementation question on another project I am working on, but this will be for another thread

Comment: If an entire folder is missing, it does not make sense to continue scans for possible sub-folders inside it. If you store your data in a tree-like structure, you can then report that 'current' path and continue with the next branch.

Comment: I thought the same for the screening part, but what about the reporting part. Each folder can contain lots of other foler and you can immagine the amount of file. So maybe even though I do not look for them, I shoud also report them. Saying folder A is missing and showinf everything that was inside... Maybe that's too much and I'm over thinking it. This is why I want your thoughts

Comment: alright guys, I'm in France and it's already 2am here. But I hope you'll have some more comments tomorrow. Especially on the doability of the project. Going throuhg thousands of file is possible in a few minutes or it will be too long... Thanks for your help